# Templating in Grafana with Elastic Search

Tags: grafana

I want to use the templating feature in Grafana with elastic search to create a set of 'dynamic' terms ("application")

To get the ist of terms from elasticsearch I'm useing:

```
{
 "aggs" : 
  { 
    "applications" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "businessTransactions.application" }
    }
  }
}
```

When I use that query in the Templating Query variable settings as query Grafana tells me: "Template variables could not be initialized: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

I'm using grafana 3.1.0beta1

Maybe I'm completely off, but how would someone use a query to get different terms of a field as a template variable from elasticsearch?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have an answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

First question: which version of Grafana are you using? Sorry just re-read and saw the answer, which is 3.1.0beta1.

The below works for me on 3.1.0 (not beta).

Second question: did you see this page: http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/elasticsearch/

> **Templating**
>
> The Elasticsearch datasource supports two types of queries
>   you can use to fill template variables with values.
>
> Possible values for a field
>   `{"find": "terms", "field": "@hostname"}`
>
> Fields filtered by type
>   `{"find": "fields", "type": "string"}`
>
> Fields filtered by type, with filter `{"find": "fields", "type": "string", "query": <lucene query>}`
>
> Multi format / All format